# Excel Transposing Every nth row to every nth column

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Been trying to figure this out for a while and every solution I've tried hasn't been terribly successful for what I'm trying.

Basically what I'm trying to do is take every other row in a spreadsheet that could be 3 to 80 columns, and transpose them into new columns next to where they were before, while deleting the now empty rows.

I want to make this:

[image: Before]

into this:

[image: After]

I've managed to get a few things working, like copying every other row, and inserting columns, but the part that seems to be evading me is making the colored columns also get copied. And as I mentioned, scaling it from any size of spreadsheet seems to also be the part that gets me the most.

Any good ideas?

Comment: You aren't performing a transpose. You are moving data up to a previous row. If you could provide an example of your code, we could provide pointers on changes you should make.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to get the colors (and other font characteristics) is to do a `Copy` process.  If this is too slow, we can investigate other options.

I would suggest

- Copy the original data to a new worksheet (so as to preserve your original data)
- Determine the last fixed column -- in your sample it is the column labeled **Dilution:**
- After the last fixed column +1, insert a new column every other column to the last actual column
- copy the information in the second row of each data set up and to the right one cell (into the now empty column).
- delete all the rows which are blank in column A

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub Interleave2()
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet
    Dim rSrc As Range, rRes As Range
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    Dim LastFixedColumn As Long
    Dim I As Long, J As Long, K As Long, L As Long

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")

With wsSrc
    LastRow = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
             LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
             searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    LastCol = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
             LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
             searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    Set rSrc = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
End With

LastFixedColumn = rSrc.Find(what:="Dilution:", after:=rSrc.Cells(1)).Column

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

wsRes.Cells.Clear
rSrc.Copy wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

For I = LastCol To LastFixedColumn + 2 Step -1
    Cells(1, I).EntireColumn.Insert shift:=xlToRight
Next I

With wsRes
    LastRow = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
             LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByRows, _
             searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    LastCol = .Cells.Find(what:="*", after:=.Cells(1, 1), _
             LookIn:=xlFormulas, searchorder:=xlByColumns, _
             searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    Set rRes = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
End With

For I = 3 To rRes.Rows.Count Step 2
    For J = LastFixedColumn + 1 To rRes.Columns.Count Step 2
        rRes(I, J).Copy rRes(I - 1, J + 1)
    Next J
Next I

With rRes
    .Columns(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    With .EntireColumn
        .ColumnWidth = 255
        .AutoFit
    End With
    .EntireRow.AutoFit
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

---

Comment: This does the trick! After that first comment I started to go in this direction so it's nice to see that I am getting better at figuring out the correct workflow.